# Historical Accuracy of Foucalt's works

Tags: history-of-philosophy, foucault, genealogy-of-morals, sexuality, history

I am beginning the "History of Sexuality" and wanted to ask to what degree should I take what Foucalt states about historical events in any of his works as accurate? From my understanding from looking online Foucalt does something similar to Nietzsche's Genealogical method. By this I understand that he takes a general outline of commonly held beliefs about history and performs a cultural analysis. Is my understanding correct?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, on the whole.

Comment: From the intro: "For a long time, the story goes, we supported a Victorian regime, and we continue to be dominated by it today. This the image of the imperial prude is emblazoned upon our mute, and hypocritical sexuality". I wonder if Foucault, if he were alive today would write the same given sex and sexuality is everywhere and sensationalised too; it seems to have given over to the simulcra and spectacle of sexuality.